# polylongdiv with terms in reverse order

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, polynomials

Is there a way to use \polylongdiv in the polynom package to display and calculate polynomials in the reverse order from the way the package is written?  For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{polynom}
\begin{document}

\polylongdiv{x^3+x^2-1}{x-1}

\end{document}
```

produces $x^2+2x+2+\frac{1}{x-1}$,

but what if I want to do

\polylongdiv{1}{1-x}

for say, the first 5 terms of the expansion?

Comment: It would be enough if anyone would at least point me to how to typeset such division!

Comment: Is this an impossibility?

Comment: Hello? Trying to keep this question alive!

Comment: You have all my sympathy: I once asked if there was a package capable of long division in **_ascending_** powers and the question was closed almost instantly. By the way, it seems that math teachers have no idea there is even such a thing. Too bad though.

Comment: Thanks @schremmer for the sympathy : )